# Looking for resources about Jimmy McDonald (Disney sound designer and voice actor)

Tags: design, resources

Hi mates,

as the title says ! 
It's hard to find material about that sound wizard around the web, so any links, videos, books or whatever warmly welcome ! 
Cheers,

Xavier

Answer (score 2):

There are two videos that touch on the amazing work of McDonald that I can think of:

[One here.](http://soundworkscollection.com/imagineering)

[And one here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSf8Er2gV_Q)

Answer (score 2):

BBC Radio broadcast a documentary about him which is no longer available to download from the BBC website, but it has been uploaded to soundcloud - http://soundcloud.com/jameschristie/the-voice-of-mickey-mouse